# how do create a test connection to informix with jdbc?

Tags: database, jdbc, wso2, informix, dbeaver

i dowloaded the Informix JDBC driver connect for  deploy it a datasource in my project, they indicated to me that i should download the Informix developer edition from Docker Hub to do a test connection first trought DBeaver and then trought ESB WSO2, but i dont have some things clear, for do a test connection to my Informix Docker container, dont i should first have an Database put in Informix?

that i should do for make my first database test connection from DBeaver??

i should put in each text box?
[image]

My Docker Container Log is the next:

```
2023-07-18 20:37:14 [2023-07-19T01:37:14Z] >>>
2023-07-18 20:37:14 [2023-07-19T01:37:14Z] >>>    LICENSE: 
2023-07-18 20:37:14 [2023-07-19T01:37:14Z] >>>    LICENSE_SERVER: 
2023-07-18 20:37:14 [2023-07-19T01:37:14Z] >>>    DBA_USER: 
2023-07-18 20:37:14 [2023-07-19T01:37:14Z] >>>    INFORMIX_PASSWORD: in4mix
2023-07-18 20:37:14 [2023-07-19T01:37:14Z] >>>    DBA_PASSWORD: 
2023-07-18 20:37:14 [2023-07-19T01:37:14Z] >>>    HQADMIN_PASSWORD: Passw0rd
2023-07-18 20:37:15 [2023-07-19T01:37:14Z] >>>    USER_MANAGEMENT: 
2023-07-18 20:37:15 [2023-07-19T01:37:15Z] >>>    SIZE: SMALL
2023-07-18 20:37:15 [2023-07-19T01:37:15Z] >>>    TYPE: OLTP
2023-07-18 20:37:15 [2023-07-19T01:37:15Z] >>>    STORAGE: 
2023-07-18 20:37:15 [2023-07-19T01:37:15Z] >>>    MEMORY_PERCENTAGE: 
2023-07-18 20:37:15 [2023-07-19T01:37:15Z] >>>    CPU_PERCENTAGE: 
2023-07-18 20:37:15 [2023-07-19T01:37:15Z] >>>    BUFFERS_PERCENTAGE: 80
2023-07-18 20:37:15 [2023-07-19T01:37:15Z] >>>    SHMVIRT_PERCENTAGE: 19
2023-07-18 20:37:15 [2023-07-19T01:37:15Z] >>>    NONPDQ_PERCENTAGE: 1
2023-07-18 20:37:15 [2023-07-19T01:37:15Z] >>>    DISK_ENCRYPTION: OFF
2023-07-18 20:37:15 [2023-07-19T01:37:15Z] >>>    DEBUG: OFF
2023-07-18 20:37:15 [2023-07-19T01:37:15Z] >>>
2023-07-18 20:37:15 [2023-07-19T01:37:15Z] >>>    MAPPED_HOSTNAME: cc62adc0b7a2
2023-07-18 20:37:15 [2023-07-19T01:37:15Z] >>>    MAPPED_SQLI_PORT: 9088
2023-07-18 20:37:16 [2023-07-19T01:37:16Z] >>>
2023-07-18 20:37:16 [2023-07-19T01:37:16Z] >>>    ONCONFIG_FILE: 
2023-07-18 20:37:16 [2023-07-19T01:37:16Z] >>>    SQLHOSTS_FILE: 
2023-07-18 20:37:16 [2023-07-19T01:37:16Z] >>>    REST_PROP_FILE: 
2023-07-18 20:37:16 [2023-07-19T01:37:16Z] >>>    MONGO_PROP_FILE: 
2023-07-18 20:37:16 [2023-07-19T01:37:16Z] >>>    MQTT_PROP_FILE: 
2023-07-18 20:37:16 [2023-07-19T01:37:16Z] >>>    DBSERVERNAME: 
2023-07-18 20:37:16 [2023-07-19T01:37:16Z] >>>    DBSERVERALIAS: 
2023-07-18 20:37:16 [2023-07-19T01:37:16Z] >>>    INIT_FILE: 
2023-07-18 20:37:16 [2023-07-19T01:37:16Z] >>>    RUN_FILE_PRE_INIT: 
2023-07-18 20:37:16 [2023-07-19T01:37:16Z] >>>    RUN_FILE_POST_INIT: 
2023-07-18 20:37:16 [2023-07-19T01:37:16Z] >>>    CONFIGURE_INIT: 
2023-07-18 20:37:16 [2023-07-19T01:37:16Z] >>>    EDITION_INSTALLER: 
2023-07-18 20:37:17 [2023-07-19T01:37:16Z] >>>
2023-07-18 20:37:17 [2023-07-19T01:37:17Z] >>>    PORT_DRDA: ON
2023-07-18 20:37:17 [2023-07-19T01:37:17Z] >>>    PORT_REST: ON
2023-07-18 20:37:17 [2023-07-19T01:37:17Z] >>>    PORT_MONGO: ON
2023-07-18 20:37:17 [2023-07-19T01:37:17Z] >>>    PORT_MQTT: ON
2023-07-18 20:37:17 [2023-07-19T01:37:17Z] >>>    TLS_CONNECTIONS: OFF
2023-07-18 20:37:17 [2023-07-19T01:37:17Z] >>>    TLS_CONNECTIONS_STATUS_FILE: /opt/ibm/config/tls_connections_status_file
2023-07-18 20:37:17 [2023-07-19T01:37:17Z] >>>    WL_CREDENTIALS_STATUS_FILE: /opt/ibm/config/wl_credentials_status_file
2023-07-18 20:37:17 [2023-07-19T01:37:17Z] >>>
2023-07-18 20:37:17 [2023-07-19T01:37:17Z] >>>    HA: 
2023-07-18 20:37:18 [2023-07-19T01:37:17Z] >>>    HA_PRIMARY: 
2023-07-18 20:37:18 [2023-07-19T01:37:18Z] >>>    HA_PRI_DBSERVERNAME: 
2023-07-18 20:37:18 [2023-07-19T01:37:18Z] >>>    HQSERVER: 
2023-07-18 20:37:18 [2023-07-19T01:37:18Z] >>>    HQAGENT: 
2023-07-18 20:37:18 [2023-07-19T01:37:18Z] >>>    HQSETUP: 
2023-07-18 20:37:18 [2023-07-19T01:37:18Z] >>>    HQSERVER_MAPPED_HOSTNAME: 
2023-07-18 20:37:18 [2023-07-19T01:37:18Z] >>>    HQSERVER_MAPPED_HTTP_PORT: 8080
2023-07-18 20:37:18 [2023-07-19T01:37:18Z] >>>    HQSERVER_MAPPED_HTTPS_PORT: 8081
2023-07-18 20:37:18 [2023-07-19T01:37:18Z] >>>
2023-07-18 20:37:18 [2023-07-19T01:37:18Z] >>>    Start container
2023-07-18 20:37:18 [2023-07-19T01:37:18Z] >>>    License was not accepted - Exit
2023-07-18 20:42:57 [2023-07-19T01:42:57Z] >>>     PIDS = 
2023-07-18 20:42:57 [2023-07-19T01:42:57Z] >>>     PIDS = 
2023-07-18 20:42:57 Warning: could not access ONCONFIG /opt/ibm/informix/etc/onconfig.
2023-07-18 20:42:57 shared memory not initialized for INFORMIXSERVER 'informix'
2023-07-18 20:42:57 [2023-07-19T01:42:57Z] >>>    INFORMIX_CLEAN param1: 
2023-07-18 20:42:57 argv[1]: (0x7ffd4283de8e) /opt/ibm/scripts/informix_entry.sh
2023-07-18 20:42:57 argv[2]: (0x7ffd4283deb1) /opt/ibm/scripts/informix_stop.sh
2023-07-18 20:42:57 Shutdown Signal Received 15:
```

in the past i used only MySQL and Postgres, but in informix i dont recognize the diference betwen the "Server" and "Host", also dont have clear if in the Docker Informix developer is for put a database the which i can do test querys, call stored procedures and funcions, etc, Docker Hub Informix Developer servers to this?

Comment: `Server` in that picture you posted refers to the name of the Informix server (INFORMIXSERVER). Based in the output, INFORMIXSERVER for that docker server is `informix`.  `Host` is the hostname or IP address for the container and `Port` is the tcp port (which should should exposed) 
Check this info in the project page (https://github.com/informix/informix-dockerhub-readme/blob/master/14.10.FC9W1/informix-developer-database.md). 
Also, your Informix server is not running as you did not specify the `-e LICENSE=accept`  parameter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are the fields with a bit of explanation.

Database/Scheam: `sysmaster` which easiest database/schema to test a connection with It's a read-only system database that all Informix systems have available. Once you have a connection, you can issue SQL statements to create a user database to do all the normal SQL work you would want.

Server: `informix` This is usually not needed and been optional for years but DBeaver keeps it in the wizard. Just fill it in.

User: `informix` every informix system has this user

Password: `in4mix` defined in the docker logs and is changeable in the container

Port: `9088` unless you mapped it to something else in the docker run

Host: `localhost` is fine unless your docker container is running elsewhere

Comment: thanks for your beautiful information