# Database test connection from WSO2 Integration Studio?

Tags: database, jdbc, wso2, wso2-esb, informix

Finally i tested correctly the connection to my database server Informix with DBeaver such as indicated to me in this question that i doid:

[how do create a test connection to informix with jdbc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76717702/how-do-create-a-test-connection-to-informix-with-jdbc)

Now, now i must do same but from WSO2 with a dataservice. the asisten is the next:

[image]

I put the url connection, her user and password:

[image]

[image]

and finally i put manually the host, the port and the database name and then do click on Test Connection and then i get the error message "Connection Failed, Could not connect to database"
Because does this? is suppoused that i stableshied correctly the each variables for do my connection and puted mi jdbc .jar driver in the correct directory ("runtime/microesb/lib"), [in the previous ask i do correctly the Informix test connection trought DBeaver][4] but now i cant do it from WSO2, someone can guide me??

Comment: Is your Informix server running? Can you exec into the container with `docker exec -it ifx bash` and run `dbaccess` to check if is up?
In your previous questions the server did not initialize as you did not use `LICENSE=accept`. 
https://github.com/informix/informix-dockerhub-readme/blob/master/14.10.FC9W1/informix-developer-database.md

Comment: Skip the test step, go ahead and create the Dataservice and then try to test it. If you still get a error add it to your question.